# INSERT INTO not working. Unique Constraint Failed (Python SQLite)

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a sorting application that picks students out of a table and puts them in form groups. Gender should be equal across the groups. It loops through each table inserting random male students.

I have used print functions to track what is happening. It seems like the loop is working since

```
print(idMale)
```

is printing rows out. However there hasn't been an insertion at all in the other table. And the program breaks and outputs this error:

[image: error message]

.

Here is my code:

```
# loops through each table
for x in range(0,groupNumber):
    #Adds I to table name to go through each table
    nameGroupList.append('I')
    print(nameGroupList)
    nameGroup = ''.join(nameGroupList)

    #loop to select a student from the main table (sessionName) and insert them into another group
    #loop number is subject to the number of males that should be in 1 group
    for x in range(0, formMaleInt):
        selectMaleRow = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + sessionName + " WHERE Gender='M'  ORDER BY random() Limit 1")
        #-----Find ID of student selected so they can be deleted from sessionName
        idMale = selectMaleRow.fetchone()
        print(idMale)
        idSepChar = list(idMale)
        idNum = idSepChar[0]
        idNumStr = str(idNum)
        #-----Find ID of student selected so they can be deleted from sessionName

        insertMaleRow = cur.execute("INSERT INTO " + nameGroup + " SELECT * FROM " + sessionName + " WHERE Gender='M'  ORDER BY random() Limit 1")
        deleteMaleRow = cur.execute("DELETE FROM " + sessionName + " WHERE ID='" + idNumStr + "'")
```

Here is my sessionName table:
[image: sessionNameTable]

Here is my other table
[image]